# SqlWorkflowInstanceStore connection string security

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation

Is there any way or workaround to supply a secure connection string when creating a .NET SqlWorkflowInstanceStore instance?

```
SqlWorkflowInstanceStore instanceStore = new SqlWorkflowInstanceStore(persistenceConnString);
```

The potential is there for a plain text connection string to have user password info.

Comment: Why not simply specify [Integrated Security](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254500(v=vs.110).aspx#Windows%20Authentication) in your connection string?

Comment: We do have integrated security when accessing from the server side, however there are instances where workflows are spun up from the client side and in that case the store may not already be created ... and from the client side we can't use integrated security.